# Python script scheduling in airflow

Tags: python, apache-spark, scheduling, reload, airflow

*Hi everyone,*

I need to schedule my python **files(which contains data extraction from sql and some joins)** using airflow. I have successfully installed airflow into my linux server and webserver of airflow is available with me. But even after going through documentation I am not clear ***where exactly I need to write script for scheduling and how will that script be available into airflow webserver so I could see the status***

As far as the configuration is concerned I know where the dag folder is located in my home directory and also where example dags are located.

**Note:** Please dont mark this as duplicate with How to run bash script file in Airflow as I need to run python files lying in some different location.

### Please find the configuration in Airflow webserver as :

[image]

### Below is the screenshot of dag folder in AIRFLOW_HOME dir

[image]

### Also find the below screenshot for DAG creation screenshot and Missing DAG error

[image]

[image]

### After i select the **simple** DAG following error of missing DAG is populated

[image]

Answer (score 41):

You should probably use the `PythonOperator` to call your function. If you want to define the function somewhere else, you can simply import it from a module as long as it's accessible in your `PYTHONPATH`.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from my_script import my_python_function

dag = DAG('tutorial', default_args=default_args)

PythonOperator(dag=dag,
               task_id='my_task_powered_by_python',
               provide_context=False,
               python_callable=my_python_function,
               op_args=['arguments_passed_to_callable'],
               op_kwargs={'keyword_argument':'which will be passed to function'})
```

If your function `my_python_function` was in a script file `/path/to/my/scripts/dir/my_script.py`

Then before starting Airflow, you could add the path to your scripts to the `PYTHONPATH` like so:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my/scripts/dir/:$PYTHONPATH
```

More information here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html

Default args and other considerations as in the tutorial: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html

Comment: Hi @postrational, Thanks for the suggestion. Please guide where to write this script in airflow which you have mentioned in your comment ? sorry I am very new to airflow..

Comment: Well, the file with the DAG definition would go in your `AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` directory. The file with your Python function could go into any directory, as long as it's on the PYTHONPATH. I added some information to my answer.

Comment: Hi @postrational, what would be the **file extension** of file containing the DAG definition? . In my airflow configuration **dags_folder** is specified as **/home/amit/airflow/dags** so I have placed the DAG definition there only.. is that right ?

Comment: That's right. The DAG definition code is Python, so the file should have the .py extension.

Comment: I have added the same.. now how to import the same into airflow UI ?? I have created the DAG runs and provided the DAG Id as "tutorial" but nothing is showing DAG entries sheet.

Comment: Have you properly set your `AIRFLOW_HOME` environment variable? You should `export AIRFLOW_HOME /path/to/your/airflow_home` and then in the `airflow_home` you should have your `airflow.cfg` file with all airflow settings including the path to your `dags_folder` etc.

Comment: Yes.. I did... when i do echo $AIRFLOW_HOME it is showing me the exact path. I have successfully created the DAG in DAG runs with Dag Id as ""tutorial". after which it show it as running but when i click on the tutorial it says DAG "tutorial" seems missing. Please find the changes in question as I have added the screenshots also.

Comment: A little bit late, but for those of you who are not sure where to put this code I highly recommend to follow those tutorials at https://www.applydatascience.com/airflow/writing-your-first-pipeline/

Answer (score 30):

You can also use bashoperator to execute python scripts in Airflow. You can put your scripts in a folder in DAG folder. If your scripts are somewhere else, just give a path to those scripts.

```
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators import BashOperator,PythonOperator
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    seven_days_ago = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(7),
                                      datetime.min.time())

    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': seven_days_ago,
        'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
      }

    dag = DAG('simple', default_args=default_args)
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='testairflow',
    bash_command='python /home/airflow/airflow/dags/scripts/file1.py',
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: Hi Navjot, Thanks for the suggestion. Please guide where to write this script in airflow which you have mentioned in your comment ? sorry I am very new to airflow..

Comment: Hope you've figured that out, but still for others, in the `dags` folder. `dags` folder location is specified in `airflow.cfg` which resides in `AIRFLOW_HOME` dir.

Answer (score 2):

Airflow parses all Python files in $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags (in your case /home/amit/airflow/dags). And that python script should retrun a DAG object back as shown in answer from "postrational". 
Now when it is being reported as missing that means there is some issue in Python code and Airflow could not load it. Check airflow webserver or scheduler logs for more details, as stderr or stdout goes there.

Comment: Thanks.... there was an issue with the python script.. resolved the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install airflow using Airflow official documentation. Its good idea to install in python virtual environment.
   http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
2. When we start airflow first time using

`airflow webserver -p <port>`

It loads examples dags automatically, It can be disable in 
$HOME/airflow/airflow.cfg

```
`load_examples = False`
```

3. Create **dags** folder in $HOME/airflow/, put tutorial.py file in **dags** folder from https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/tutorial.html
4. Do some experiments, make changes in tutorial.py. If you are giving schedule_interval as cron syntax, then `'start_date' : datetime(2017, 7, 7)`

   ```
   'start_date': datetime.now()
   ```

   `dag = DAG('tutorial', default_args=default_args,schedule_interval="@once")`
        or 
   `dag = DAG('tutorial', default_args=default_args,schedule_interval="* * * * *") # schedule each minute`
5. start airflow: `$ airflow webserver -p <port>`
6. start scheduler: `$ airflow scheduler`