# How to pass parameter to PythonOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I just started using **Airflow**, can anyone enlighten me how to pass a parameter into **PythonOperator** like below:

```
t5_send_notification = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t5_send_notification',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=SendEmail,
    op_kwargs=None,
    #op_kwargs=(key1='value1', key2='value2'),
    dag=dag,
)

def SendEmail(**kwargs):
    msg = MIMEText("The pipeline for client1 is completed, please check.")
    msg['Subject'] = "xxxx"
    msg['From'] = "xxxx"
    ......
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.send_message(msg)
    s.quit()
```

I would like to be able to pass some parameters into the `t5_send_notification`'s callable which is `SendEmail`, ideally I want to attach the full log and/or part of the log (which is essentially from the kwargs) to the email to be sent out, guessing the `t5_send_notification` is the place to gather those information.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

1. Pass a dict object to *op_kwargs*
2. Use the keys to access their value from *kwargs* dict in your python callable

   ```
   def SendEmail(**kwargs):
       print(kwargs['key1'])
       print(kwargs['key2'])
       msg = MIMEText("The pipeline for client1 is completed, please check.")
       msg['Subject'] = "xxxx"
       msg['From'] = "xxxx"
       ......
       s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
       s.send_message(msg)
       s.quit()


   t5_send_notification = PythonOperator(
       task_id='t5_send_notification',
       provide_context=True,
       python_callable=SendEmail,
       op_kwargs={'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'},
       dag=dag,
   )
   ```

Comment: that didn't work. it should be like: `SendEmail(key1, key2, **kwargs):`

Comment: @Amin which version of the airflow you are using? the reason why I asked is that you might be using python3 as the latest versions of airflow support python3 much better than a year ago, but still there are lots of people using python2 for airflow dev.

Comment: If it has something to do with python version please mention it in the answer.

Answer (score 21):

[PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html) have a named parameter `op_kwargs` and accepts `dict` object.

have

```
t5_send_notification = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t5_send_notification',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=SendEmail,
    op_kwargs={"my_param":'value1'},
    dag=dag,
)

def SendEmail(my_param,**kwargs):
    print(my_param) #'value_1'
    msg = MIMEText("The pipeline for client1 is completed, please check.")
    msg['Subject'] = "xxxx"
    msg['From'] = "xxxx"
    ......
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.send_me
```

Comment: Thank you Ethan, your code of `op_kwargs={my_param='value1'},` reports error.

Comment: `{key : value}`

Comment: Do you have the entire error? Is the key in quotes as well?