# How I can access parameters passed to airflow DAG

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG that is triggered externally with some additional parameters say 'name'.

Sample code:

```
with airflow.DAG(
        'my_dag_name',
        default_args=default_args,
        # Not scheduled, trigger only
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    start = bash_operator.BashOperator(
        task_id='start',
        bash_command='echo Hello.')

    some_operation = MyOperator(
        task_id='my_task',
        name='{{ dag_run.conf["name"] }}')

    goodbye = bash_operator.BashOperator(
        task_id='end',
        bash_command='echo Goodbye.')

    start >> some_operation >> goodbye
```

Now if I use `{{ dag_run.conf["name"] }}` directly with the echo for a BashOperator, it works. Another way to read the parameter is to use a `PythonOperator` where I can read conf by `kwargs['dag_run'].conf['name']`.

However, what I really want is to have the `name` beforehand so that I can pass it while construction of the MyOperator.

Comment: Unfortunately that information is only available during execution, hence the `dag_run` name on the variable -- it can be accessed during workflow construction because it doesn't exist yet.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh, I see. I was basically trying to use [GoogleCloudStorageToS3Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_s3.html) and thought It would be great if I could externalize the source and target needed by this operator.

Comment: What do you mean by 'externalize'? This operator takes two parameters: `google_cloud_storage_conn_id` and `dest_aws_conn_id`. The names of the connections that you pass into these parameters should be entered into your airflow connections screen and the operator should then connect to the right source and target.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894418/how-to-pass-parameter-to-pythonoperator-in-airflow