# What is **context in Python

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to Python. Trying to pick up Airflow. What is `context` or `**context` in Airflow that is used in methods? For example mentioned by the answer in this question [Airflow Python Script with execution_date in op_kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093718/airflow-python-script-with-execution-date-in-op-kwargs)

Or like in

```
 def execute(self, context):

 def is_business_account(**context):
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Comment: It is used for handling variable length arguments in python. It has nothing to do with airflow.